# Why are custom height measures not working in my tailwind.config.js?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have been working on a project with NextJS and Tailwind CSS.

I need to use the height class `h-96` for a couple of components, but since it is not default-defined I decided to added it to my `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './ui/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      height: {
        '96': '24rem',
      },
      // https://vercel.com/design/color
      colors: {
        vercel: {
          primaryGreen: '#92c700',
          primaryBlue: '#111871',
          primaryPurple: '#5c068c',
          secondaryPurple: '#6d0793',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I was expecting to be able to use `h-96` but it seems that the configuration in the `tailwind.config.js` file are not been applied to the project.

NOTE: I also tried to set the height like this:

```css
height: {
  96: '24rem',
},
```

since the linting auto-corrected it for me, but this didn't work either.

Comment: What version of Tailwind are you running? There's already a value for `h-96` in v3.0.

Comment: Im running 3.2.4
I realized that the class does not appear on the dist.css, does that means I had a problem while installing it?

Comment: Tailwind parses your code when it builds and only includes the utility classes that it finds there. Have you tried rebuilding your code/CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

Height 96 (h-96) is a default theme. Since you are attempting to override a default, you must add it directly under the theme tab because you are not 'extending' anything, but rather changing the default configuration.

- **Source:** [Here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#overriding-the-default-theme)

**Try this:**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
      content: [
        './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './ui/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
      ],
      theme: {
        height: {
            96: '24rem',
          },
        extend: {
          // https://vercel.com/design/color
          colors: {
            vercel: {
              primaryGreen: '#92c700',
              primaryBlue: '#111871',
              primaryPurple: '#5c068c',
              secondaryPurple: '#6d0793',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment:)
The problem is that I cannot use it
It doesn't even appear in the dist.css file
Do you know why that might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

`h-96` is already defined in the tailwind css classes. You can update the `h-96` default value in the `tailwind.config.js` in the following way.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      height: {
        '96':'124rem'
      }
      // ...
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Also , if you are just using it for couple of components, you can also directly change the values in the components itself like `h-[124rem]`.

More info [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height#arbitrary-values)

Comment: Thank you for your comment:)
But I have not been able to use it
Even in the dist.css file it does not appear as defined
Do you know why that might be happening?